# Backbone localStorage doesn't use the good sync method

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, local-storage, commonjs

I'm going crazy with my problem !

I have a model where i want to use localStorage, but when i call model.fetch in my view, i got the error "Error: A "url" property or function must be specified".

This error is "normal" if i wasn't using localStorage, because i didn't define the url property. Here the fetch call should be using Backbone.sync (aka Backbone.localSync override by localStorage module right ?).

But it never enter the localStorage functions ! As if the module was never loaded. But i added some console.log everywhere and backbone.localstorage is loaded and initialize correctly.

It's like Backbone is reloaded somewhere and i loose the override on Backbone.sync pointing to localStorage.localSync...

Error happens in the modules/config.js, render function.

Here is my code :

models/configuration.js' :

```js
var Backbone = require('Backbone');
    Backbone.LocalStorage = require('Backbone.LocalStorage');

    // Exports the module
    module.exports = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            id: 1
            agencyName : 'xxx',
            agencyId : 'xxx',
            serviceUrl : 'xxx'
        },

        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('Configuration')
    });
```

data/configuration.js :

```js
'use strict';

// Get class dependencies
var Config = require('../models/configuration');

// export module
module.exports =  new Config();
```

controller/config.js :

```js
'use strict';

// Gets the controller dependencies
var region = require('../regions/main'),
    dispatcher = require('../services/dispatcher'),
    ConfigView = require('../modules/config'),
    config = require('../data/configuration');

// manages the route for the home page
module.exports = function() {
    dispatcher.command('header:set', [ 'Configuration', false, true]);
    region.show(new ConfigView({model: config}));
};
```

modules/config.js :

```js
'use strict';

// Adds the requires for the module
var Backbone = require('Backbone');

// Exports the header module
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Sets the template
    tpl: require('../templates/config.tpl'),

    // Sets the class for the Module
    className: 'home module',

    // Sets the event for the menu module
    events: {
        'mouseup': 'onScreenTap'
    },

    // Fired when the user clicks anywhere in the menu, to close it
    onScreenTap: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // if a menu item was clicked, it navigates to the module
        var node = e.target;
        if (node.classList.contains('btn')) {
            this.model.save();
        }
    },

    // Initializes the module
    initialize: function () {
    },

    // Renders the view
    render: function () {
        this.model.fetch();

        this.$el.html(this.tpl({ config: this.model }));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the problem !!
Everywhere i was using "require("Backbone")" but in backbone.localStorage.js, backbone was required with "require("backbone")" !
So 2 instances of Backbone were cached and i was not using the good one.. 3 days fighting this i'm exhausted !

Hope this will help someone one day..